# jquery/pdfobject is not showing pdf in rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf

Hi I am working on rails. I want to display PDF in my web site. I tried **[PDFOBJECT](http://pdfobject.com/)** jQuery plugin. I downloaded the pdfobject.js and require it through application.js. The javascript part I used is given below as given in the document.

```
<div id="pdfObject">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var url = "<%= "#{Rails.root}/AJITH.pdf" %>";
 console.log('url:'+url);
 window.onload = function(){
 var myPDF = new PDFObject({ url: url, pdfOpenParams: { view: "FitV" }     }).embed("pdfObject");
 };
```

But in browser it not showing the pdf. It only showing a grey colored box. While taking inspect element it showing

```
<div id="pdfObject">
  <object data="rails_root/AJITH.pdf#view=FitV" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

In javascript console it showing an error like

GET localhost:4000/rails_root/AJITH.pdf 404 (Not Found)

I am not able to find the solution,can anyone help me to find the solution

Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Place the PDF file in your public directory and just point to it using Javascript only:

```
var url = "/AJITH.pdf"
```